# Resharper naming-conventions Export

Tags: naming-conventions, resharper

Is there a way to export the re-sharper's code guidelines / naming-conventions to an XML file?

Answer (score 1):

Open Visual Studio
Go to Resharper > Options...
Under Langagues > Common > Code Style Sharing
Choose Export...

And Choose a file name and locaion.